# How to translate rectangle position?

Tags: java, libgdx, position, rectangles

I have a rectangle that gets created every 3sec.

```
 public void newRect(){
        rect=Pools.obtain(Rectangle.class);
        rect.set(rX, Y, 90, 90);
        rectangles.add(rect);//adding to the ArrayList
    }//this method gets called when condition==true
```

The problem is that I get errors when I do this

```
while(rectIterator.hasNext()){
   Rectangle rect=rectIterator.next();
}//and I don't know how to make the rectangle move(all the rectangles that spawns).
```

On my sprites I was able to do this

```
 while(sprIterator.hasNext()){
            Sprite spr=hIterator.next();
            spr.draw(batch);
            spr.translateY(600*deltaTime);
        }
```

UPDATE
error I get when I initialize Rectangle rect

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at com.msl.explode.Bitter.draw(Bitter.java:49)
    at com.msl.explode.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:51)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Comment: do this `Rectangle = rectIterator.next()` is intentional? or you were trying to say something like `Rectangle rec = recIterator.next()`?

Comment: what kind of error do you get? post the stacktrace or logcat

Comment: are you modifying the `rectangles` collection outside in other method/thread? are you using the `.remove()` method? try to post how do you create the `recIterator` object... This exception is saying to you that someone is using/updating your collection and this is not permissible. From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html): *it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it.*

Comment: no I haven't been using .remove() method yet,     rectangles=newArrayList<Rectangle>();
rectIterator=rectangles.iterator();

Comment: basically when newRect() method is called it creates a rectangle and add it to rectangles ArrayList

Comment: Also do you know how to translate the rectangles Y coordinate? just like what I did on my sprites

Comment: Can you show us the routine that calls `newRect()`?  I suspect `rectangles.add(rect);` may be whats causing the `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 1):

You've got a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):
I suggest you use a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of a classic [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Do you have any Idea how to make the rectangle move?